# Stop a child div from creating padding, but only on one div id in css

Tags: html, css, parent

I am using Joomla to create a website at the moment and I am having problems with a certain module getting padding applied to it. The problem is with Joomla you have classes for the modules that I cant seem to override. The layout is as follows :

```
    <div id="rt-page-surround">
    <div class="rt-container">
    <div class="rt-container-bg">
    <div id="rt-drawer">
    <div id="rt-header">
    <div class="rt-grid-6 rt-alpha">
    <div class="rt-grid-6 rt-omega">
    <div class="thumbnail_scroller">
    <div class="rt-block">
    <div class="module-content">
    <div id="jdv_iscroll122_wrap" class="jdv_iscroll_wrap " style="width: 620px; height: 110px; ">
    <div id="jdv_iscroll122_inner" class="jdv_iscroll_inner horizontally" style="width: 32766px; height: 110px; left: 0px; ">
    </div>
```

The module I am trying to modify is thumbnail_scroller, the problem is it is getting 15px of padding from rt-block. If I set rt-block to padding:0px this gives the desired affect to thumbnail_scroller but it also applies the zero padding to everything else on the page as the rt-block class is shared with numerous other elements on the page (this is the way the template is coded by the author). What I want to do is apply zero padding to rt-block but only for the thumbnail_scroller module.

I have tried

```
.thumbnail_scroller {padding:0px !important}
```

but this seems to do nothing, anyone any ideas on this one ? :-)

Comment: Try with: .thumbnail_scroller {padding:0 0 0 0 !important;} Maybe you just forgot the semicolon at the end

Comment: Hi, nope that doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div.thumbnail_scroller div.rt-block {
    padding:0;
}
```

This specifically targets divs with the rt-block class that are inside a div with the thumbnail_scroller class.

Answer (score 2):

You can be hyper-specific by trying something within your CSS like:

```
div.thumbnail_scroller div.rt-block {

    padding: 0px;
}
```

That directive will then apply only to a `div` of class `thumbnail_scroller` IF it sits within a `div` container of class `rt-block`.

(Edited for `div` order - re-read your question.) {:¬)